# Will changing the password of some user also change the sudo password?

Tags: sudo, password

I am the only user of my Linux Mint system and I noticed that the password I chose to login is the same that got assigned to `sudo`.

So my question is: Will changing my login password also change the `sudo` password?

If not, how can I change the `sudo` password?

Comment: It isn't the sudo password, it's your password.

Answer (score 45):

By default, `sudo` asks for *the user password*. Thus, changing the user password (which is also used for login), will also affect sudo invocations.

However, you can set in the `/etc/sudoers` for your user the `rootpw` flag, in which case it would ask for the root password instead.

The relevant excerpt from the [sudoers(5) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) is:

```
Authentication and logging
 The sudoers security policy requires that most users authenticate them‐
 selves before they can use sudo.  A password is not required if the
 invoking user is root, if the target user is the same as the invoking
 user, or if the policy has disabled authentication for the user or com‐
 mand.  Unlike su(1), when sudoers requires authentication, it validates
 the invoking user's credentials, not the target user's (or root's) cre‐
 dentials.  This can be changed via the rootpw, targetpw and runaspw
 flags, described later.
```

Similarly, the keyword for *not* requesting a password for sudo is *NOPASSWD*.

If you want to set the root password, you can use `sudo passwd`

Note that when changing sudo permissions, it is recommended to keep a root console open (eg. `sudo -s`) until it is verified in a different terminal that it indeed works, and you haven't locked out yourself.

Comment: And you can specify that a user (or group of users) may use `sudo` *without* being prompted for their password at all.

Comment: You should also mention how to set the `root` password. Configuring `sudo` to require the `root` password without first setting the `root` password could be problematic.

Comment: While this is true, it's generally considered a bad idea to have a "root password" known to administrators.  Consider how much damage could be done by an administrator who changed it and then left.  Best practices generally call for administrators to be members of a group (such as "wheel") in `/etc/sudoers` that can elevate to root by using their own password, rather than a shared password.

Comment: @MontyHarder that's the same harm the same rogue administrator could do removing everyone from the wheel group or changing the contents of /etc/sudoers The main benefit is not to avoid evil administrators (you are giving them root!) but avoiding direct logins as root (thus keeping a log of actions).

Comment: @kasperd, BaardKopperud: added

Answer (score 22):

There's no `sudo` password on its own. A user can belong to the `sudo` group and run the `sudo` command, but each user has only one password. When it changes, it changes for the user not any application in particular.

Another similar misconception is that the root password is the same as one used for `sudo`ing. No, *root* is a single user and has a private password, which has nothing to do with any other password.

Comment: That's how `sudo` is usually configured by default. But that configuration can be changed.

Comment: Or [`wheel` group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29)…

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `sudo` uses the same "password database" (usually `/etc/shadow` for a small system) as login.

Comment: On sane systems, certainly. But since sudo can have a separate `pam.d/` config, not-so-sane systems might exist that do things like "login with kerberos/ldap auth, yet sudo with local password database". (Yes, this will not apply to the OP's single-user Mint.)